# Php Sql Array in to Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, implode

If we have 3 arrays for example:

```
Array= a, b, c. 
Array2= 1, 2, 3  
Array3= 0, 4, 5
```

I want to insert them in to my sql table like this

```
A 1 0
A 2 4
A 3 5
B 1 0
B 2 4
B 3 5
C 1 0
C 2 4
C 3 5
```

All second and third array values will be stored with each and every value of first array.

How can i do that? Using php and sql

Comment: What database (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, SQLite, ...) and API (PDO, mysqli, etc.) are you using?

Comment: All of them support prepared statements. So prepare a statement with placeholders for each column, and bind it to 3 variables. Then loop through the arrays, setting the variables to the corresponding elements of each array, and execute the statement.

Comment: Start with loop basics before diving into these.

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: Please can i have an example? I know it can be done by looping but how?

Comment: In retrospect, I wish I would have agreed with others that the question Needs Clarity, but I prefer to give askers a nudge in the right direction when they show absolutely no coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Itterate first array by value, inside this loop itterate second array by index, take values from second and third array by this index:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'db_username', 'secret_password');

$array1 = ['a','b','c'];
$array2 = [1,2,3];
$array3 = [0,4,5];

$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO your_table set string_column = ?, integer_column1 = ?, integer_column2 = ?");

foreach( $array1 as $string_value )
    foreach( array_keys($array2) as $integer_index )
        $sth->execute( $string_value, $array2[ $integer_index ], $array3[ $integer_index ] );
```

Comment: You don't need `array_keys()`, you could use `foreach ($array2 as $index => $value2) {` then use `$value2` and `$value3[$index]`.

Comment: I know, but i believe with `array_keys` code looks more clean.